# Checking existence of registry key value in for loop batch

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry

I am writing a batch script to check if a registry key value exists and I am having some issues.
When I directly specify a key to look for, the `%ERRORLEVEL%` updates appropriately. The example below echos the value 1 as expected.

```
REG QUERY HKLM /v NONEXISTENT_KEY
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

However I am checking the existence of a bunch of keys in a file so I am looping over it with `FOR`. The following echos 0 for some reason that I do not understand.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%A IN (myFile.txt) DO (
    REG QUERY "%%A" /v "%%B"
    ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Note: the structure of the file I am looping over is demonstrated in the following example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\PATH\TO\KEY,SOME VALUE
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) together with `ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!`?

Comment: Just tried this, the error level is still returned as 0 despite the key value not existing.

Comment: **EDIT** Sorry I forgot to change my '%'s to '!'s. It works after doing that.

Comment: Yes, just confirmed by testing. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The following `echo`s `0` for some reason that I do not understand.

> ```
> FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%A IN (myFile.txt) DO (
>     REG QUERY "%%A" /v "%%B"
>     ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
> ```

You need to [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) together and use `ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!`.

Corrected batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%A IN (myFile.txt) DO (
    REG QUERY "%%A" /v "%%B"
    ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!
  )
endlocal
```

Output:

```
> type myFile.txt
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\PATH\TO\KEY,SOME VALUE

> test
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
1
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Comment: What is the role of `EnableDelayedExpansion`? I can't understand from ss64, can you explain it?

Comment: @Biswa In a loop you must use delayed expansion to evaluate a variables value each time the loop is executed. Without delayed expansion it is evaluated only once when the batch file is parsed (that happens when it is read).