# Batch move files to different subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've about 600 files that I want to move to different subfolders based
on the number at the beginning of the filename.

E.g.

```
5--US-L.jpg -> subfolder /5/5--US-L.jpg

7--US-M.jpg -> subfolder /7/7--US-M.jpg

34--A3-RAW.jpg -> subfolder /34/34--A3-RAW.jpg

87--US-L.jpg -> subfolder /87/87--US-L.jpg

127--US-L.jpg -> subfolder /127/127--US-L.jpg

162--US-L.jpg -> subfolder /162/162--US-L.jpg
```

It's numbered from `1` to `162`.
Tried to move all that is before `"--"` into the designated subfolder but no luck.

Comment: Does it have to be cmd or can it be powershell?  You could do it in vbscript or jscript as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be something like this? You have to drag and drop the folder where the files are to the batch...

```
@echo off

if /i exist "%~1" (if /i not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)
pushd "%~1"
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do For /f "delims=-" %%b in ("%%~a") do call :MoveF "%%~a" "%%~b"
pause
exit

:MoveF
IF not exist "%~2" md "%~2"
move "%~1" "%~2"
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Comment: I love this method.  That is also how I would have done it.  +1 for using call/batch functions and the nice animation! :)  ¡Viva el friki!

Answer (score 1):

- To move from 1 to 162 files:

In command line:

```bat
@for /l %l in (1 1 162)do 2>nul @md .\"%~l" & @move "%~l--*.jpg" .\"%~l"\ >nul
```

In batch file:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "d:\Target\Folder"

for /l %%L in (1 1 162
)do md .\"%%~L" & move "%%~L--*.jpg" .\"%%~L"\ >nul
```

---

- To move from 1 to 999 files if any exist:

In command line:

```bat
@for /l %l in (1 1 999)do @if exist "%~l--*.jpg" 2>nul @md .\"%~l"\ & @move "%~l--*.jpg" .\"%~l"\ >nul
```

In batch file:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "d:\Target\Folder"

for /l %%L in (1 1 999)do if exist "%%~L--*.jpg" 2>nul (
    mkdir .\"%%~L"\ & move "%%~L--*.jpg" .\"%%~L"\ )>nul
```

---

Using drag and drop or pre-set path to target folder:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal

(cd/d "%~1" || cd/d "Z:\SU-2022\Q1699812" 
) >nul 2>&1 || ( endlocal & goto :eof ) 

for /l %%L in (1 1 999)do if exist "%%~L--*.jpg" 2>nul (
    mkdir .\"%%~L"\ & move "%%~L--*.jpg" .\"%%~L"\ ) >nul
```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[For /L](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)**
- **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
- **[`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**
- **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/1670957/batch-for-loop-not-recognizing-its-own-variable/1674454#1674454)**