# Calling a Recursive Function in a Batch File

Tags: batch, echo, recursive

I am currently trying to write a batch file for a project that will mimic the structure of the following pseudocode:

```
void h ( int n ) 
     if ( n ≥ 4 ) 
          h ( n / 2 ) 
     end if 
     print n 
end h
```

And generate the following output:

```
2
4
8
16
```

When the function is given **16** as input.

This is the closest I've come so far:

```
@ECHO off
SET /A number=%1 
IF %number% GEQ 4 (
    CALL recursive-36 number/2
REM The following line returns 4, 8, 16.
REM ECHO %number%
)
REM The following line returns 2, 2, 2, 2.
ECHO %number%
```

No matter where I put the ECHO %number% statement, however, I can't get 2, 4, 8, 16 as output. Why is that? Is this a pass-by-reference thing? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You write `IF %number% GEQ 4 ( `which means if number is greater or equal to 4. That is why it never does a 2. Isn't it enough to change that to `GEQ 2`?

Comment: That's a good point, and I've wondered about that myself. But does that mean there error's actually in the pseudocode as well? (So it would seem.)

Comment: I would say so, yes. Although on the other hand, 4 divided by 2 would become 2. So on second thought somehting else seems to go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive algorithm in batch can be written like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A number=16
echo %number%
call :recursive
goto :eof

:recursive
if %number% gtr 2 (
  set /A number/=2
  echo %number%
  call :recursive
)
exit /b
```

References :

- [SETLOCAL](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [EXIT](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)
- [Operations on Variables](https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/19059/operations-on-variables)

Comment: Alternate solution, make the batchfile call itself with 2 parameters, the init value and the max, and it parses the current value to the init parameter until init is larger than max.

Comment: `recurseive` is a label and not a function. All variables are available and usable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off 

if not "%~1" == "" (
     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     set "_n=0")else exit /b 1

%:^0     
if %~1 geq 4 (
     set /a "_n=%~1/2"
     echo;!_n! & call %:^0 !_n!
    )else endlocal && exit /b 0
```

---

- Results/Outputs:

[image]

---

- For Reverse Outputs/Results:

```bath
@echo off 

if "%~1"=="" (exit /b 1)else set "_n=0"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

%:^0     
if %~1 geq 4 (
     set /a "_n=%~1/2"
     call set "_out=!_n!,!_out!"
     if !_n! neq %~1 call %:^0 !_n!
     exit /b)else for %%i in (!_out!)do echo;%%i

endlocal & exit /b 0
```

- Outputs/Results:

[image]
_ _

**1.** You can treat your bat as a function, since it already starts receiving an argument.

**2.** If no arguments are passed, it aborts/exits, if any are passed, it loops with if + call it handles the division and prints the result...

**3.**
For a better understanding of how to handle/operate one with a label/function in bat, see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1674454/969781):

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please feel free to make use of it d;)