# How to sort lines in files by custom order?

Tags: batch, text-editing

How can we sort content within a large number of files based on the first word encountered on a line before a separator? In a **custom sort order**.

I will explain this with examples. Say I have hundreds of files that look as below (the files below are very short on purpose, in reality they all have about 100 fields per file):

##### file 1

```
headb_mask,*off
neck,models/players/az/hair1
headc_eyes,models/players/az/face_1
headc_face,models/players/az/face_1

torso_collar,*off
torso_hood,*off
torsoa,models/players/az/torso_1
r_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
l_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
```

##### file 2

```
headb_mask,*off
headc_eyes,models/players/az/face_2
neck,models/players/az/hair1
headc_face,models/players/az/face_2
torso_collar,*off
torsoa,*off
torso_hood,models/players/az/torso_1
r_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
l_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
```

I want them all to follow this **custom sort order**:

```
headc_eyes,
headc_face,
headb_mask,
neck,

torso_collar,
torso_hood,
torsoa,
l_arma,
r_arma
```

so the post-processed files will look like this:

##### file 1

```
headc_eyes,models/players/az/face_1
headc_face,models/players/az/face_1
headb_mask,*off
neck,models/players/az/hair1

torso_collar,*off
torso_hood,*off
torsoa,models/players/az/torso_1
l_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
r_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
```

##### file 2

```
headc_eyes,models/players/az/face_2
headc_face,models/players/az/face_2
headb_mask,*off
neck,models/players/az/hair1

torso_collar,*off
torso_hood,models/players/az/torso_1
torsoa,*off
l_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
r_arma,models/players/az/torso_1
```

How can we accomplish this? There are hundreds of files like these, and manually it will take many hours. Any technique is good.

Comment: That order is unclear -- why should l_arma be *after* torsoa?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I edited the question to note its' supposed to be ` In a custom order.` - based on some template provided by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_TMPFile=%temp%\Some#_Uniq#_Name#_%Random%_."
set "_order=headc_eyes,headc_face,headb_mask,neck"
set "_order=%_order%,torso_collar,torso_hood"
set "_order=%_order%,torsoa,l_arma,r_arma"

for %%i in =;( *.txt );= do >"%_TMPFile%" =;(  for %%# in =;( %_order%
    );= do for /f useback^delims^= %%G in =;(` find.exe /i "%%~#" ^<"%%~i" `
    );= do <nul set^ /p "`=%%~G" & echo/);= && move /y "%_TMPFile%" "%%~nxi"
```

---

- Or...

```bash
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_order=dc,db,ck,ll,oo,oa,l_,r_"
set "_TMPFile=%temp%\Some#_Uniq#_Name#_%Random%_."

for %%i in =;( *.txt );= do >"%_TMPFile%" =;(  for %%# in =;( %_order%
    );= do for /f useback^delims^= %%G in =;(` find.exe /i "%%~#" ^<"%%~i" `
    );= do <nul set^ /p "`=%%~G" & echo/);= && move /y "%_TMPFile%" "%%~nxi" >nul
```

---

Define your order and use your order in loops as a filter:

**1.** Use a `for` loop to select file by text file (`%%~i`)

**2.** A second `for` loop will separate line for use in filtering the lines of each file (`%%~i`) one ordered item at a time (`%%~G`) in the custom order

**3.** A third `for /f` will apply a single occurrence (`%%~#`) at a time per file as a filter to the already selected file, returning the first occurrence based on the comma

**4.** Redirect the output to a temporary file(`>TMPFile`), then use it to replace the original by `move /y`

---

## Some further reading:

- **[Sort /?](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html)**
- **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
- **[What does **`%~dp0`** mean, and how does it work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)**
- **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/1670957/batch-for-loop-not-recognizing-its-own-variable/1674454#1674454)**